# How to input application sounds to other applications?

Tags: sound

On the mac there is an application called [Soundflower](https://soundflower.en.softonic.com/mac) which is able to change the input audio device to be the application audio output.

Thereby passing the audio output from one application to another.

Is there something similar for Ubuntu?

Comment: see https://jackaudio.org/